# Angular2 passing errors from observed service to calling app

Tags: angular

I have an app which consists of three classes: app (component), httpService (which brings some data via http) and middleService (which processes the data)

So, the flow of control is: app calls a function in middleService which calls a function in httpService which finally calls angular2 http(). And then data is travelling back asynchronously. Errors (e.g. page not found) should also travel back, but they don't, and that's the problem.

Here is the code:

app.ts

```
constructor(private middleService: MiddleService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.data = '';
  }
  getData() {
    this.action = 'click';
    this.middleService.getData$
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          debugger;
          this.data = data
        },
        error => {
          debugger;
          this.error = error;
        }
      );
    this.middleService.getData();
  }
```

middleService.ts

```
constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
    this.getDataSubject = new Rx.Subject<any>();
    this.getData$ = this.getDataSubject.asObservable();
  }
  getData(): void {
    this.httpService.getData()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          debugger;
          let newData = 'new ' + data;
          this.getDataSubject.next(newData);
        },
        error => {
          debugger;
          return Rx.Observable.throw(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

httpService.ts

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getDataSubject = new Rx.Subject<any>();
    this.getData$ = this.getDataSubject.asObservable();
  }
  getData(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get('./resource/data.txt')
      .map(res => res.text())
      .catch(error => {
        debugger;
        return Rx.Observable.throw(error.text());
      });
  }
```

Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WE6xm7BxXuL1fOT7F053?p=preview).

The last piece of code in httpService contains http.get('./resource/data.txt'). This file exists and the data is passed back up to app.ts.

But if you change the file name to dataaaa.txt, there is "page not found" error. This error is visible in httpService, middleService, but not in app (it isn't displayed and the debugger doesn't stop in the error branch in app.ts).

My question is, how to write the middleService to pass the error to app? (with assumption that it must be in the middle between app and httpService)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MiddleService`, don't throw an exception, pass the error to the subject.

[Edited Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L52XBCW3twsJn6ytvmIC?p=preview)

```
error => {
      debugger;
      this.getDataSubject.error(error.status);
      //return Rx.Observable.throw(error);
    }
```